# Firefox add-on To Open A List Of Sites With IE By Default

Tags: firefox

There are several Firefox addons that let you right-click on a link and open with Internet Explorer.

I am looking for an addon that has a list of URLs or Domains in its settings and automatically opens IE if any of those sites are opened.

This should apply to links clicked within Firefox but also if I click a link in Outlook and it opens Firefox by default, this should then redirect to IE.

Having the right-click Open-With functionality for items not in that list is also a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used **[IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab)** for this purpose at a customers site a long time (there were intranet pages which only worked in IE). You have the right-click here "on demand", but also can configure URL patterns where Firefox should always use the IE engine for (pages are still opened inside Firefox, but using an "embedded IE"):

[image: URL config] [image: external program]
<sup>*IE Tab* configuration (source: [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the second screenshot shows, you could even define any "external browser" to be used.

Note that this addon was last updated in 2013, so you might wish to rather use its successor **[IE Tab V2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36)** instead.